# Android ListView Header Disable Click

Tags: android, listview, header, click

I'm using [isEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) in my BaseAdapter of ListView and controlling which rows can be clickable. However, I want to disable click event for my header and isEnabled does not work. Position 0 points the first row, therefore I can not control header click.

On the other hand, when I add header using [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) giving arguments (header, null, false) , it works but dividers are missing in that way. How can I manage this?

Is there anyone who knows this problem?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use `addHeaderView(header, null, false)`. For the header, inflate a view which has your header content with a divider underneath. This view is what I used for the divider.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="#adaaad" />
```

Comment: Using addHeaderView(view, null, false) worked.  addHeaderView(view) apparently defaults to "selectable".

Comment: This may remove list item separators - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367278/issue-with-addheaderview-and-missing-list-separator/14368524#14368524
If you want all listview items and header non-selectable, you can set `code`listView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);`code`. This will keep separators.

Comment: It's an old question but I'd like to point out that on some devices the default value is selectable and on the other majority not selectable. So it's good to always use the three arguments method.

Comment: addHeaderView(view, null, false) worked Thanks a lot...