# Issue with addHeaderView and missing list separator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm using

```
mList.addHeaderView(mHeader, null, false);
```

in Android add an (unselectable) header to my list. When the list is rendered the header isn't selectable however the list separator (the line) between the bottom of the header and first list item is missing. Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
mList.addHeaderView(mHeader)
```

In you onItemClick method take in consideration the extra index.

Comment: Thanks, but if I use mList.addHeaderView(mHeader) the list header still turns blue when you click on it (holo theme). I don't want it to turn a different color when tapped.

Comment: Add this to your listview: android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"