# how to make header of listview not to consume the touch event

Tags: android, listview, touch-event

**What I want**

I want the header of listView not to consume the touch event

**Problem**

I have a FrameLayout.In it, there are a mapview and a listview. The listview has a transparent header view in order to show more of the mapview. Now the header view response to the touch events, but I want dispatch these events to the mapview. How to do?

**I have tried**

- `headerView.setEnabled(false)`
- `headerView.setClickable(false)`
- `mListView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false)`

All of them failed, any advice?

Comment: the only way i can think to prevent the header to consume the touch event is setting its visibility to Invisible.

Comment: Think you @Anders. I tried your solution, but not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try a lot of solutions in SO, but they are not work.Finally, I override the `dispatchTouchEvent()` function, it works.Complete version is over [gist](https://gist.github.com/jiachenning/c93d8c19c139c57ff61b171a85baacf7)
,and key code is in here.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(mHeaderView == null) return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        //if touch header not to consume the event
        Rect rect = new Rect((int) mHeaderView.getX(), (int) mHeaderView.getY(), mHeaderView.getRight(), mHeaderView.getBottom());
        if(rect.contains((int)motionEvent.getX(), (int)motionEvent.getY())){
            isDownEventConsumed = false;
            return isDownEventConsumed;
        }else {
            isDownEventConsumed = true;
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    }else{
        //if touch event not consumed, then move/up event should be the same
        if(!isDownEventConsumed)return isDownEventConsumed;
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set `onClickListener` null while inflate header view or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670102/android-listview-header-disable-click)?

Comment: I tried , but not work. finally I override the `dispatchTouchEvent()` function, it works~