# Android listview header pass through touch to view behind

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have a listview with a custom class header which is completely transparent. Behind the list view, I have a mapview which shows through the transparent header.

I am trying to make this work so that if the user is scrolling my touching any of the rows on the listview, then the listview scrolls. But if the user is touching the top transparent header part of the listview, then the listview should not intercept the touches and should instead pass it to the mapview behind (which lets the user pan/zoom on the mapview).

I am unable to achieve this currently as the listview keeps stealing the touches all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735963/how-to-make-header-of-listview-not-to-consume-the-touch-event?rq=1).

Use a custom ListView class:

```
package xxx.xxx.xxxxxx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HeaderUntouchableListView extends ListView {
    private View mHeaderView;
    private boolean isDownEventConsumed;

    public HeaderUntouchableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addHeaderView(View v) {
        super.addHeaderView(v);
        this.mHeaderView = v;
    }

    @Override
    public void addHeaderView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable) {
        super.addHeaderView(v, data, isSelectable);
        this.mHeaderView = v;
    }

    /**
     * list header should not consume the event, and list item should consume the event
     * consumed here is replaced with super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)
     * @param motionEvent
     * @return is event consumed
     */
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(mHeaderView == null) return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //if touch header not to consume the event
            Rect rect = new Rect((int) mHeaderView.getX(), (int) mHeaderView.getY(), mHeaderView.getRight(), mHeaderView.getBottom());
            if(rect.contains((int)motionEvent.getX(), (int)motionEvent.getY())){
                isDownEventConsumed = false;
                return isDownEventConsumed;
            }else {
                isDownEventConsumed = true;
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        }else{
            //if touch event not consumed, then move/up event should be the same
            if(!isDownEventConsumed)return isDownEventConsumed;
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    }
}
```